# Set a dynamic `activateAccountSuccessPath`

Tags: config, routing

How to set a dynamic path for `activateAccountSuccessPath` that contains the username (or any other field from the user profile)?

Answer (score 2):

Completely untested, but something like this should do it.  Create a simple [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) and add this to the main plugin class:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('users.onBeforeActivateUser', function(Event $event)
    {
        $user = $event->params['user'];

        craft()->config->set('activateAccountSuccessPath', 'members/'.$user->username);
    });
}
```